# Next fire time for a non-concurrent job with paused triggers

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I want to get the next time a job is scheduled to execute in quartz.net. The job is non-concurrent and may have multiple triggers, some of which are paused.

While the job is executing, all triggers in the status `NORMAL` are set to blocked. All triggers in the status `PAUSED` are set to `PAUSED_BLOCKED`. Quartz.net reports triggers that are in the status `PAUSED_BLOCKED` as `Blocked` while a job is executing.

I tried the following code:

```
private DateTimeOffset? GetNextFireTime (JobKey jobKey)
{
    var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob (jobKey);
    return triggers.Where (IsActive).Select (x => x.GetNextFireTimeUtc ()).Min ();
}

private bool IsActive (ITrigger trigger)
{
    return IsActive (scheduler.GetTriggerState (trigger.Key));
}

private static bool IsActive (TriggerState state)
{
    return state == TriggerState.Normal || state == TriggerState.Blocked;
}
```

The problem is that it also includes paused triggers, many of which have a next fire time in the past. I cannot exclude the blocked triggers though, otherwise I will also ignore triggers that are not paused.

The problem is most noticeable when using a single fire trigger. This causes all the other triggers to report their status as `blocked`, but the single fire trigger reports its status as `Complete`. If blocked triggers are ignored the result is that no next fire time is found. If blocked triggers are included the result is the paused trigger is include and the next fire time is in the distant past.

Comment: What version of "Quartz.Net" are you using?

Comment: Can you put a sample case somewhere where we can test it?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in AdoStoreSupport https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/193#issuecomment-54633427

Comment: Here's an example in linqpad, the output shows how the next execute time keeps jumping back into the past because of the paused trigger. https://gist.github.com/chilversc/530a2031c32f5c3735c8#file-output-txt